# Angular scrollable mat-selection-list?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a question. I didnt find any familiar question on stack so i asking here, is it possible to make `<mat-selection-list>` scrollable (Angular 7)? I want to display scroll-bar on the right when items are too many to fit a window.

```
<mat-card fxFlex="33%">
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-item
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    [class.selected]="product === selectedproduct"
    (click)="onSelect(product)"
  >
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample example first?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple CSS

```
mat-selection-list {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-yggqi9?file=app/app.component.css)

Comment: Why 400px?  Is it possible to make the list fill its parent, instead of cutting it off at a certain place?

Comment: @piccy You have to set height somewhere, otherwise there will be no scrollbar.

Answer (score 6):

By setting custom CSS properties?

CSS for fancy scroll bar which only supports Chrome browsers:

```
.custom-scroll-bar{
    height:70vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.custom-scroll-bar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 5px;
}

.custom-scroll-bar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.26);
}
```

For Firefox and Internet explorer just simply use:

```
.custom-scroll-bar{
    height:70vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes class="custom-scroll-bar">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

[`StackBlitz Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfqnbt)

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

```
<mat-card fxFlex="33%">
     <mat-selection-list [style.overflow]="'auto'" [style.height.px]="'300'">
         <mat-list-item
              *ngFor="let product of products"
              [class.selected]="product === selectedproduct"
              (click)="onSelect(product)"> 
     </mat-list-item>
</mat-selection-list>
```